# How to re-write arrow function to regular function and bind context?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

I am checking the arrow function introduced in ES6. If I have this piece of code with the function "addNinja":

```js
 addNinja=(ninja)=>{
         ninja.id=Math.random();
         let ninjas=[...this.state.ninjas,ninja];
         this.setState({
             ninjas:ninjas
         })
        console.log(this.state);

 }
```

Is there any way that this can be written without the arrow function?

If I taking into account that these 2 are the same...

```js
x=>x*2 

function(x){
return x*2;
}
```

I will assume that I could rewrite the addNinja function like the code below but I get an error.

```js
 addNinja=function(ninja){
         ninja.id=Math.random();
         let ninjas=[...this.state.ninjas,ninja]; 
         this.setState({
             ninjas:ninjas
         })
        console.log(this.state);

 }
```

Comment: *"but I get an error"* - The error message might be a clue as to what the error is.  Though if I'm to guess I'd think the binding of `this` is different between the two.

Comment: unfortunately just converting the arrow function to a regular function is unlikely to work because of the difference in how `this` is treated in both scenarios.

Comment: the error is: Cannot read property 'ninjas' of undefined

Comment: "If I taking into account that these 2 are the same..." you'd be believing falsehoods. arrow functions cannot become methods (i.e. don't set `this` to the receiver object like "proper" functions, but treat `this` as any other variable under closure).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `function() {}` syntax does not bind the local context to the function, that is why `this.setState` or `this.state.something` fails, because `this` is defined by the global lexical context, and the `state` does not exist in it. If you want to achieve this you have to manually bind the function:

```
constructor(props) {
  this.addNinja = this.addNinja.bind(this);
}

addNinja=function(ninja){
         ninja.id=Math.random();
         let ninjas=[...this.state.ninjas,ninja]; 
         this.setState({
             ninjas:ninjas
         })
        console.log(this.state);
}
```

Comment: It is unlikely `this` is `undefined` - it will be defined by its lexical context, which is likely to be the global object. Nevertheless +1.

Comment: True, thanks, updated the answer

Comment: Just calling  `this.addNinja.bind(this)` won't help, you will need to do something with the result. Also, this looks like a `class` body, and then you should use method syntax for `addNinja`

Comment: I knew I was forgetting something :P

Comment: Just a simple question: Can you bind the class methods somewhere else than inside the constructor?  If so, what is the advantage of doing it there?

Comment: Don't think so, the constructor function is called when the class is instanciated, therefore `this` is actually binded to the context, any other functions will not be binded to the context